# Been following w3schools coding how to's, cant get the dropnav to work with an code attempts

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

Im learning to code via the website w3schools and am having issues with the dropbox navs, I could only get it to half work with this code;

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>CSS Template</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    /* Style the top navigation bar */
    
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #4682B4;
      -
    }
    /* Style the topnav links */
    
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    /* Change color on hover */
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #5F9EA0;
      color: black;
    }
    /* Style the content */
    
    .content {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 30px;
      height: 400px;
    }
    /* Style the footer */
    
    .footer {
      background-color: #4682B4;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    /* Style The Dropdown Button */
    
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#">Store</a>
    <a href="#">Village</a>
    <a href="#">Forum</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Profile</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>

      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
      <h2>Home Page</h2>


    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <p>Footer</p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have also tried [the drop down nav here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp) which just totally wrecks my code so far. I have no idea why it wont work

The one above 'works' but only at the end of the line. Adding the dropdown button to before 'store' results in the whole line disappearing, the same effect happens if I move it to anywhere but the end of the nav.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I can see that may help you:

1. You are missing a closing div for the dropdown class:

```
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">Store</a>
  <a href="#">Village</a>
  <a href="#">Forum</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Profile</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. You're giving a `float: left` to all `.topnav a` tags. Since your dropdown-content a tags are nested, they will not get picked up by that CSS. Therefore, if you try to place that dropdown-content div before a different link, it will never be floated left with the other a tags and will remain last. If you're wanting to rearrange the order of the links, I would suggest [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It's a great, simple way to create a responsive navbar!

If you'd like to keep using float, you would need to change the following CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    /*position: relative;*/
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```